# Simple two button counter html jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Jquery and Javascript. I've only done the intros for codeacademy and I have what I remembered from my python days.

I saw this tutorial:
http://www.codecademy.com/courses/a-simple-counter/0/1

I completed the tutorial and thought: "I should learn how to do this with Jquery".
So I've been trying to use what I understand to do so. My issue is that I don't know how to pass an argument for a variable from HTML to Jquery(javascript).

Here is my code:
**HTML**

```
<body>

<label for="qty">Quantity</label>
<input id="qty" type = "number" value = 0 />
<button class = "botton">-1</button>
<button class = "botton">+1</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Jquery/Javascript:**

```
//create a function that adds or subtracts based on the button pressed

function modify_qty(x) {
    //on click add or subtract
    $('.botton').click(function(){
        //get the value of input field id-'qty'
        var qty = $('#qty').val();

        var new_qty = qty + x;

        //i don't want to go below 0
        if (new_qty < 0) {
                new_qty = 0;
        }
    //put new value into input box id-'qty'
    $('#qty').html(new_qty)
    })
};


$(document).ready(modify_qty);
```

How do I pass an argument of 1 or -1 to the function? I was using onClick() but that seemed redundant because of the $('.botton').click(function(){}).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use data attributes on your buttons you can get the value you want.

HTML:

```
<button class = "botton" data-value="-1">-1</button>
<button class = "botton" data-value="1">+1</button>
```

JS:

```
function modify_qty() {
    //on click add or subtract
    $('.botton').click(function(){
        //get the value of input field id-'qty'
        var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val());

        var new_qty = qty + parseInt($(this).data('value'));

        //i don't want to go below 0
        if (new_qty < 0) {
                new_qty = 0;
        }
    //put new value into input box id-'qty'
    $('#qty').val(new_qty)
    })
};

$(document).ready(modify_qty);
```

More compact JS:

```
$(function() {
    //on click add or subtract
    $('.botton').click(function(){
        //get the value of input field id-'qty'
        var $qty = $('#qty'),
            currentValue = parseInt($qty.val());
        $qty.val(Math.max(0, currentValue + parseInt($(this).data('value'))));
    })
});
```

Update:
Realized you could do this without the data attributes if want to since your button text is the same as your value.

```
$(function() {
    //on click add or subtract
    $('.botton').click(function(){
        //get the value of input field id-'qty'
        var $qty = $('#qty'),
            currentValue = parseInt($qty.val()),
            newValue = currentValue + parseInt($(this).text());

        $qty.val(Math.max(0, newValue));
    })
});
```

Comment: It works. And the best part is I know (basically) why. I have some more google searches to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5haaq8v4/4/) to help you grasp the what's going on. Basically, the reference to the element that triggered the event is `$(this)` or event.target. Things get a bit more complicated with self refence depending on the context you are in, however for `$('selector').on('event',function(event){ console.log($(this)) //is the reference to $('selector') });`. `.attr()` -> list of the element's attributes.